# Canvas won't display the lines in an animation I am trying to create. What is wrong with my HTML/JS?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm writing JS code which is supposed to place lines on a `canvas`. The lines should start at random locations and stop at random locations, with random colors to eventually fill up the canvas.

In the JS file, I have two functions. One that is picking the random `color(randomColor())`, and the other function, `discoShow()`, is supposed to create the lines with a `setInterval()`, so that the function is repeated.

At the top of the canvas I have two buttons with a `onclick` event listeners to start and stop the animation. I have also included a paragraph that is displaying the color of the current color that is inserted in the canvas, and a `console.log` that says the starting and the ending position of the current line.

The color is displayed in the paragraph and the console is showing my `moveTo()` and `lineTo()` positions, so I know that the `discoShow()` function is working. However, something is wrong. No lines are drawn in the canvas when I click the start animation button that I have created.

I am new to JS, so it's probably a silly mistake somewhere that I can't see. Can you guys help me find it?

```js
notRunning = true;

function randomColor() {
  let letter = "0123456789ABCDEF".split('');
  let color = "#";

  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letter[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function discoShow() {
  let verPos = Math.floor((Math.random() * 399) + 1);
  let horPos = Math.floor((Math.random() * 399) + 1);
  let theColor = randomColor();
  let canvasID = document.getElementById("animationDisplay");
  let context = canvasID.getContext("2d");

  context.lineWidth = 10;
  context.strokeStyle = theColor;

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(horPos, verPos);
  context.lineTo(horPos, verPos);
  context.stroke();

  console.log("Vertical position: " + verPos + " Horizontal position: " + horPos);

  document.getElementById("displayColor").innerHTML = theColor;
}

let animation;

document.getElementById("startShow").onclick = function() {
  if (notRunning) {
    animation = setInterval(discoShow, 100);
    discoShow();
    notRunning = false;
  } else {
    alert("Sorry, already running!");
  }
}

document.getElementById("stopShow").onclick = function() {
  clearInterval(animation);
  notRunning = true;
}
```

```css
#container3 {
  width: 100 vw;
}

#canvasDiv {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

#animationDisplay {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.aniButton {
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div container3>
  <div id="canvasDiv">
    <button id="startShow" class="aniButton">Start animation</button>
    <button id="stopShow" class="aniButton">Stop animation</button>
    <canvas id="animationDisplay" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <p id="displayColor"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your

```
context.moveTo(horPos, verPos);
context.lineTo(horPos, verPos);
```

are getting the same coordinates, thus not drawing a line.
The lineTo-function needs the other end of the intended line.

Comment: Ok, thank you! So I have to create two new variables with Math.random()? So that I end up with with a seperate variable for each start and end position? I thought that since the variable is choosing a random position, that I can use the same variable. That's probably wrong, yeah. s

Comment: I just updated the code and now it works perfectly! Thank you for your reply. I'm learning something new everyday with JS :)